# Excel to Text via batch without installations

Tags: excel, batch-processing

Is it possible to convert an excel file to a tab delimited file without any installation of excel? Is there any dlls that I can utilize and call via command line? I am tasked with this task that I can't find a resolution to. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: What kind of Excel file?

Comment: xlsx, one sheet

Comment: Just unzip it and parse the internal xml into txt. Easy-peasy.

Comment: can you please elaborate?